# Google Play Services LocationClient in library project

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, location-client

Please help me to understand what I must to do.
I have library (in jar) that uses LocationClient class but now LocationClient is deprecated and not available in GooglePlayServices. If anybody will try to add my library to the project and set in dependencies last version of GooglePlayServices than will be something like ClassNotFoundException ? And how I can resolve that issue ? If I will change my code for using GoogleApiClient than most apps that not updates min version of GPS will not works with my library ? Or may be I missing something about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocationClient has been removed. You should update your library to use GoogleApiClient. Our developers.android.com training section has been updated with a [set of lessons](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) that show you how to start from scratch if you aren't already using GoogleApiClient for other Google Play services APIs. The location APIs have been part of GoogleApiClient for a little while so your library users shouldn't be required to use the newest version of Google Play services, but they typically should be doing that anyway.